# Copy a Text/Image generated in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would know if it's possible to copy in html a specific code section

As you see I receive a text and an image

[image]

In my console I can see the html code

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/338504/pexels-photo-338504.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=750&amp;w=1260" alt="Desktop" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>Welcome to the world of desktops. Whether you’re looking for a powerful gaming PC or an everyday workstation, we have something to suit your needs. Our range of desktops are designed to provide the perfect balance between performance and portability, so you can stay productive wherever you are.</p> ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I used the clipboard js to copy but it does not take in consideration the image and the html code.

Do you have any idea to resolve this and take in consideration just the html code generated ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Initialize the clipboard
  var clipboard = new ClipboardJS("#copyButton");

  // Handler for when the copy button is clicked
  clipboard.on("success", function (e) {
    // Show a tooltip indicating that the text was copied
    $(e.trigger).attr("data-original-title", "Copied!").tooltip("show");
    e.clearSelection();
  });

  $("#send").click(function () {
    let message = $("#messageGpt").val();
    let engine = $("#engine").val();

    $.post(
      "' . $url . '",
      { message: message, engine: engine },
      function (data) {
        $("#TexArea-output").html(data);
        // Show the copy button after the chat message is generated
        $("#copyButton").removeClass("d-none");
      }
    );
  });
});
```